LED Recessed Ceiling Lights started going out one by one
So recently, we had a certified electrician come out and install some LED recessed lights in a small room and our big basement room, but I am slowly starting to have problems...
In the small room, I have about 5 LED recessed lights with are all connected to a dimmer, slowly one by one started randomly not powering on over the course of 2 months and now only 1/5 actually turn on.
In the big room, I have about 8 LED recessed lights on 2 dimmers (4 lights / dimmer) - When I have both dimmers turned on to max light output, after about 2 or so hours, they will automatically dim themselves.
Just trying to figure out what might be the problem and what to look into when I call another electrician since it's been close to 3 months since the previous one did work, so that ship has sailed.

The LED bulbs must be the type that work on dimmers.  Not all LED bulbs can work on dimmers.  The dimmer also must be a type for LEDs.  Some older dimmers are not good for LEDs.  Might also got a batch of defective bulbs or something is not right in the circuit.

If your original electrician is any good, he will stand behind his work from 3 months ago. I suggest that you give him a chance to investigate and explain what is going on and make it right for you. If you are unhappy with his response, then at that point get someone else.

Check that the LEDs you have are rated for use in an enclosed fixture. Recessed ceiling fixtures can trap a lot of heat, and LED bulbs (or more specifically the driver electronics in them) don't like heat.

This could be from a bad set of dimmers, or a bad set of LEDs, or both, or an incompatibility between the LEDs and the dimmers, or bad connections, or unstable power.
They could be cheap LEDs or cheap dimmers. LEDs run on direct current (DC), but most electric supplies around the world are alternating current (AC). Electronic drivers are used to convert house AC to DC for the LEDs. Electronic drivers are also used in the dimmers to control how the LED drivers adjust the LED output. Cheap manufacturers will use the smallest-capability (therefore cheapest) electronic components to get the drivers to work long enough so when the parts fail, the consumer won't bother to get the device replaced under warranty. If your LEDs or dimmers were from cheap stock, then you may be suffering from bad drivers.
You could try replacing the dimmers with basic switches and have the lights on full brightness. See if the bad lights come back. If so, the dimmers were at fault somehow. Also confirm that the LEDs are compatible with being dimmed, and that the dimmers will work with LEDs.
Have another electrician confirm that the wiring connections are adequate, and that there are no voltage fluctuations in the house power or in the rooms. It is possible for loose connections at the lights to cause loss of operation, or for interference or varying voltage to confuse the electronics in the drivers.
